# How to see functions' parameters and descriptions on Sublime Text 3?

Tags: php, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I see it on Notepad++ in advance (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>), but I dont find functions' parameters. I need PHP, MySQLi etc functions' descriptions or parameters tip.

I need something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: If it's a built-in function, <functionname> + TAB should give you the function parameters hint.

Comment: such as count+tab = count(var). i looking for like notepad++ hint: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RV8w8.jpg

Comment: That's exactly what it does, @Orhan. Is that not what you were asking?  If not, please edit your question to explain the situation better (and include a screenshot, if you can.)

Comment: i push mistakenly enter :)

Comment: screenshot is here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RV8w8.jpg

Comment: That's better. I've added the screenshot for you, @bukalemun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature is not available in ST. Currently, the API does not support popups/tool tips. I suppose it would be available, in some limited way, through customized auto complete entries, but those would likely only be common/library functions. You may need to do some further investigation into php packages.

Comment: thanks, i found a few package. all autocomplate, php modern, php completion kits, php doc, php namespace etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try PHPintel

- Install PHPintel using Package Control
- Create or open a project with PHP files
- Run the command PHPIntel: Scan Project command from the command palette (Ctrl + P in windows)

After the initial scan, PHP files will be automatically re-scanned whenever you save them.

https://github.com/jotson/SublimePHPIntel

Answer (score 1):

Sublime-IntelliDocs has similar feature.

https://github.com/shortcutme/Sublime-IntelliDocs

> ### Usage
>
> Set your cursor over a function or object you want to look up and press <kbd>F2</kbd> to see relevant documentation

Answer (score 0):

I found it: [Docblockr](https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-jsdocs)

it is show the function hint